# WCF - Retrieve JSON Body from System.SystemModel.Channels.Message

Tags: c#, json, wcf, post, router

My original Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract(
    Namespace = "http://my.framework/superservices/myservice",
    Name = "IMyServiceContract")]
public interface IMyServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyFaultContract))]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetMyItemListJSONMC")]
    GetListResponse GetMyItemListJSONMC(GetListRequest request);

    // Other methods like this.
}
```

The request I want to send with POST to my service:

```
[MessageContract]
public class GetListRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int NbItems {get;set;}

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public DateTime? InputDate { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string AnotherParameter { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public MyItem ACoolItem { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(
    Namespace="http://my.framework/superservices/myservice/types",
    Name="MyItem")]
public class MyItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public int BirthYear { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? BirthFullDate { get; set; }
}
```

The response I want to get from my service:

```
[MessageContract]
public class GetListResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public List<MyItem> Result { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string ReceivedUsername { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string ReceivedPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Client Code:

```
private void CallService<TRequest, TResponse>()
{

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestedUri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            DataContractJsonSerializer serRequest = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TRequest));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serRequest.WriteObject(ms, requestObject);
                String json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(json);
                }
            }


            // Read Response
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    string temp = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                    return Deserialize<TResponse>(temp);
                }
                return default(TResponse);
            }
}
```

The original Service Config:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="security"
    name="HttpGetUseEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="JSONBehavior"
    contract="ServiceContracts.IMyServiceContract"/>
```

```
  <endpointBehaviors>

    <behavior name="JSONBehavior">
      <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="True"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="20000000"/>
    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>


    <behavior name="InternalServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1500" maxConcurrentSessions="1500" maxConcurrentInstances="1500"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="20000000"/>
    </behavior>
```

With this service, I can send JSON Request using POST and handle them in my service implementation like this:

```
[ServiceBehavior(Name = "MyService",
    Namespace = "http://my.framework/advertiserservices/myservice")]
public class MyService : IMyServiceContract
{
    public GetListResponse GetMyItemListJSONMC(GetListRequest request)
    {
              // Do the Job and return the response.
    }
 }
```

Now, I want to replace this service implementation by a kind of routing implementation where I could catch all the requests to any service method of my contract. To do this, I adapt the configuration:

```
<service name="ServiceImplementation.RoutingService"
behaviorConfiguration="InternalServiceBehavior">
<endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="security" name="HttpGetUseEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="JSONBehavior" contract="ServiceContracts.IRouterService"/>
</service>
```

I implement my router interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRouterService
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "*")]
    Message ProcessMessage(Message message);
}
```

and the service implementation itself:

```
    public Message ProcessMessage(Message message)
    {
        UriTemplateMatch uriTemplate = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch;
        string methodName = uriTemplate.RelativePathSegments.First();

        // Routing)
        switch (methodName.ToUpper())
        {
            case "GETMYITEMLISTJSONMC":

               // 1st try to retrieve the JSON from Message:
                 TypedMessageConverter converter = TypedMessageConverter.Create(typeof(GetListRequest), string.Empty, string.Empty);
                 GetListRequest typedMessage = (GetListRequest)converter.FromMessage(message);

               // 2nd Try to retreive JSON from Message
               GetListRequest request = message.GetBody<GetListRequest>();

        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateJsonResponse(new GetListResponse());
           break;

          }
    }
```

**Now finally comes my problem and my question:**

Running this code and debugging, I am expecting the incoming System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message in input to contain a pure JSON structure but looking with QuickWatch, I see some kind of plain-XML mixed with JSON brackets:

```
{<root type="object">
  <ACoolItem type="object">
    <BirthFullDate type="null">
    </BirthFullDate>
    <BirthYear type="number">1981</BirthYear>
    <FirstName type="string">Cool First Name</FirstName>
    <LastName type="null">
    </LastName>
  </ACoolItem>
  <AnotherParameter type="string">jsonPost</AnotherParameter>
  <InputDate type="string">/Date(1395414903106+0100)/</InputDate>
  <NbItems type="number">5</NbItems>
</root>}
```

This makes that I cannot deserialize the request on service side, because both techniques exposed in the code abover expects JSON.

How can I get the input Message to contain pure JSON instead of this curious mix of JSON and XML?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar, and in this case I did use `message.GetBody`, and it worked fine. For younger versions of .net, consider using `message.GetReaderAtBodyContents` instead. I did not setup any special serialization on server side.

Try reading the body as a stream, and read that into a string. You can pass that string to a json deserializer. Notice that I have not specified any special RequestFormat. Here's some example code on the server side (using behaviour webhttp & webhttpbinding:)

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
            UriTemplate = TestService.ROUTER_URL, 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        Message Router(Message message);
    }

public class TestClass
{
    public string test { get; set; }
}

public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public const string ROUTER_URL = "/Router/*";

    public Message Router(Message message)
    {

        TestClass testClassInstance;
        /*
        (See further down for .net 4 solution)
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(message.GetBody<Stream>()))
        {
            testClassInstance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }*/

        return WebOperationContext.Current.CreateJsonResponse(new { Whatever = "yes"});
    }
}
```

On client side I just do like:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();

using (var upstream = webClient.OpenWrite(url, "POST"))
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(upstream))
    {
        writer.Write("{ \"test\" : \"json\" }");
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

The `message.GetBody` method seems to work badly when using a version younger than .net4.5. Here's another solution that works with .net4. In your service method, do this instead:

```
using (var reader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
{
    reader.Read();

    var whatever = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ReadContentAsBase64());
    testClassInstance = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(whatever);
    Console.WriteLine("Server: testClassInstance.test = {0}", testClassInstance.test);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave it a try, and it seems not to work as expected: the way you are sending the data on client-side, without specifying something like content type "application/json; charset=utf-8" implies that what I receive on service-side is "... Stream ...". If I try to open that stream with the GetBody<Stream> Method as you explained, the statement throws the following exception: "Expecting element 'Stream' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Binary', namespace ''."

Comment: Well if you set up your service differently it will probably not work out of the box. Have a look at this [pastebin with a working console app](http://pastebin.com/y9w6uNGV) that you can debug, that implements my example. Incrementally add your behaviours, contracts, and headers and see where the two meets. This way you can link a header or config change to exceptions that you get at message.GetBody().

Comment: Really curious.. I copied 1 to 1 your code into a console application in the main file and started it in debug mode. I get the exact same issue: the message parameter on service side contains "... Stream ..." and the GetBody<Stream> throws the following exception: "Expecting element 'Stream' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.IO'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Binary', namespace ''."

Comment: Curious indeed. I re-ran my code from the pastebin to see if it wasnt a copy paste error but GetBody<> works fine. I'm on win8 / .net 4.5 / VSPro2012 , what's your platform? Do you have anything in your application config? mine is empty aside from `<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>`

Comment: My app.config: <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup> and I'm running with VS 2010 and Win7 and .net 4

Comment: I confirmed your exception under a virtual WinXP/.net4.0
I am guessing the default deserialization method differs... harder for me to experiment though, as I can't debug on the xp machine

Comment: Thanks for this information. This could mean that this is related to .net 4, because the OS is different... sounds interesting... Maybe it would work If I run this with .net 4. Since I'm running with the company's PC I'll need a couple of agreements to be able to install this on my machine, but I'll give it a shot asap. If somebody has the ability to try this with win7 and .net 4.5 in between then it would even be an argument for my request. Thanks for your info ;-)

Comment: That sounds unneccessarily complicated. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I could now reproduce your first example and get it running. I then incrementally added/adapted the part so that I can get my example running and I could see why I got this curious XML at the input in my Message...

Comment: ...This was only due to the fact that the client specifies "application/json". If I specify "text/javascript" instead, then it works and I get this "...stream..." in input Message, which I can handle as you told me with the Edit. I'm not sure if this content type is Okay, because If I use a "normal" JSON Service, without this router stuff I always get Bad Request. I cannot really understand why the normal service works with application/json and return BadRequest with text/javascript and if I replace the service with the router I must use text/javascript instead of application/json...

Comment: ...If you know more about that then thanks in advance for telling me more ;-) (I checked the question as solved, because I consider the primary issue is solved. Thanks a lot for this ;-))

Comment: well it sounds a tad to complicated to say something just from your comment... If you don't figure it out, try posting a new question!